# Null ID after Grails save()

Tags: hibernate, grails, null, save, flush

Getting a strange error and have given up on googling for an answer that solves my problem. Here's my domain

```
class UserTest {

    User user
    Integer testId
    String testAgency
    String testType
    Date testDate

    static mapping = {
        table 'user_test'
        id generator: 'identity', name: 'testId', type: 'long'
        testId column: 'test_id'
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        testAgency(blank: true, nullable: true)
        testType(blank: true, nullable: true)
        testDate(blank: true, nullable: true)
    }
}
```

here's my SQL script which created my table

```
CREATE TABLE user_test (
   test_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
   test_agency varchar(128) NULL,
   test_type varchar(128) NULL,
   test_date datetime NULL,

   user_id int NULL foreign key references user_data(user_id),

   PRIMARY KEY (test_id)
)
```

and here's where I'm attempting to save in `UserController`

```
def saveTest(String id) {
    def user = User.findByUserId(id)
    def test_to_add = new UserTest(testAgency:params.testAgency,
                                   testType:params.testType,
                                   testDate:params.testDate,
                                   user:user)
    user.addToTests(test_to_add)
    user.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    user.refresh()
    redirect(action:'profile', id:user.userId)
}
```

However I'm getting the error

```
Class
    org.hibernate.AssertionFailure
Message
    null id in UserTest entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

with the line `user.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)` highlighted. I've done a bunch of googling and can't find anything helpful. Does anyone see anything off the bat as to why the IDENTITY(1,1) nature of the `testId` isn't auto-incrementing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def saveTest(String id) {
def user = User.findByUserId(id)
def test_to_add = new UserTest(testAgency:params.testAgency,
                               testType:params.testType,
                               testDate:params.testDate,
                               user:user).save(failOnError: true)
user.addToTests(test_to_add)

redirect(action:'profile', id:user.userId)
}
```

Comment: Viola! It works. I had some small issue on the DB side, but fixed it and this works now. Thanks a million!